# How to spot * in regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

I want to spot and delete all lines that have `***` in them. How can I do this?

I tried to use regex but got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 6
```

Here is my regular expression: `(?m)^**.*`.

```
.........text...........
***..........text....... //want to delete this line
........................
```

Comment: [`Pattern.quote("***")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that`*` is a special character in regex so you have to use `\\*`

Your expression will be: `(?m)^\\*\\*.\\*`

Comment: I think the dot should be removed, based on my understanding of the questioner's needs (the dot in his original regex was wrong).

Answer (score 4):

The `*` character in a regular expression has a special meaning. To show the Pattern you don't mean for this special meaning, you have to "escape" it. The easiest way to do it is to put your expression through `Pattern.quote()`.

For example:

```
String searchFor = Pattern.quote("***");
```

Then use that string to search

Answer (score 1):

This is not perfect, but it'll get you started:

```
// 4 lines, 2 of each containing "***" at random locations
String input = "abc***def\nghijkl\n***mnop\n**blah";
// replacing multiline pattern starting with any character 0 or more times, 
// followed by 3 escaped "*"s, 
// followed by any character 0 or more times
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(?m).*\\*{3}.*", ""));
```

Output:

```
ghijkl

**blah
```

Answer (score 1):

If the three asterisks are not always at the begining of the line, you can use this pattern that removes newlines too:

```
(\r?\n)?[^\r\n*]*\Q***\E.*((1)?|\r?\n?)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you're doing is looking for three specific characters together in a string, you don't need a regex at all:

```
if (line.contains("***")) {
    ...
}
```

(But if things get more complicated and you do need a regex, then use a backslash or `Pattern.quote` as the other answers say.)

(This is assuming you're reading lines one at a time, instead of having one big long buffer containing all the lines with newline characters.  Some of the other answers handle the latter case.)